# how do I change width of ng-container inside mat-table

Tags: css, angular-material, formattable, ng-container

The width of columns(ng-container) inside the mat-table is equally divided. Is there a way I can adjust based my requirements (contents on column).
Ex. In below image, checkbox is taking equal width as other columns which is not what I need.

```
<mat-table #table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource"> 
<!-- Checkbox Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">  
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
<mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                  [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                  [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && 
!isAllSelected()">  
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
<mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                  [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                  [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() &&    
 !isAllSelected()">
</mat-checkbox>
</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
<mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                  (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                  [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
</mat-checkbox>
</mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="paymentcode">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Family Code </mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.paymentcode}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flex.

'column_name' will be the matColumnDef of the column

```
.mat-column-'column_name'{
   flex: 0 0 50px;
}
```

like for select

```
.mat-column-select{
   flex: 0 0 50px;
}
```

Comment: not working, at least for angular 13

Comment: The parent needs to be set to `display: flex` for this to work